# Invalid type: Schema.AccountShare.RowCause

Tags: apex, accountshare

I'd like to either return type `Schema.AccountShare.RowCause` like this:

```
private static Schema.AccountShare.RowCause getRowCause(String rowCause) {
    // TODO: add switch statement
    return Schema.AccountShare.RowCause.Manual;
}
```

or pass the type into a method:

```
public static void shareAccount(..., Schema.AccountShare.RowCause rowCause) {
    // TODO: implement this method 
}
```

But I am getting the below error when I push my code to by sandbox org:

> Invalid type: Schema.AccountShare.RowCause

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I set up [a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102273/discussion-on-question-by-robs-invalid-type-schema-accountshare-rowcause) for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in the method signature:

```
private static Schema.AccountShare.RowCause getRowCause(String rowCause) {
// TODO: add switch statement
return Schema.AccountShare.RowCause.Manual;
}
```

`Schema.AccountShare.RowCause` is a property of type String so your method should be:

```
private static String getRowCause(String rowCause) {
    // TODO: add switch statement
    return someStringMatchingALegitimateRowCause
}
```

reference: [rowCause values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm?search_text=rowcause)